# what is Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

Basic tests do not pass

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

I am on Ubuntu 14 lts 64 bits

Docker version

```
Client version: 1.3.1
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 4e9bbfa
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.1
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 4e9bbfa
```

Error message:

```
 Error pulling image (latest) from ubuntu, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (511136ea3c5a64f264b78b5433614aec563103b4d4702f3ba7d4d2698e22c158)
```

What is this error message means

```
Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the code that is throwing this error](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/4e9bbfa90054cd730e81b53b2de67a74306afc95/registry/session.go#L168-L193), it seems like you didn't get a response when trying to contact the registry (otherwise the status code would be set to that response).

This could happen for a variety of reasons, though a firewall / network issue is the most likely one.

Turning on debug logging (on the Docker daemon, which you might have to restart for that to take effect) should make the error apparent in the Docker daemon logs (there is a `Debugf` statement a few lines up with the actual error).

---

Generally speaking, the Docker code is pretty readable, and it's easy to get to the right version since you have the git commit in `docker version`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run the container with an image version:

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

or

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```